# Mascara campo Porcentagem e Dinheiro usando somente numero?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-mobile

Tenho uma pagina html feita para celular, gostaria de colocar 2 tipos de mascara sendo % Percentual e R$ Dinheiro porém preciso que esse campo seja **type="number"** para mostrar o teclado numérico do celular.
Já baixei várias mascaras e nenhuma consegui fazer funcionar desse modo, poderiam me ajudar por favor?

Comment: Eu nunca vi algo do tipo, nem em input do tipo text. Qual o problema em colocar no final da label (%) ou (R$). Tipo: "Digite o valor(R$)" ou  "Digite o valor em reais"? Geralmente é assim que é feito. O que você quer fazer é injetar um caracteres inválidos em um campo que restringe o conteúdo. Tenho quase certeza de que isso é impossível. No site da W3C ta bem claro "The <input type="number"> is used for input fields that should contain a numeric value."

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o jQuery Mask Plugin(http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.money2').mask('000.000.000.000.000,00', {reverse: true});
});     
</script>

<input type="text" class="money2" >
```

Comment: eu já tinha visto esse plugin, ele até funcionaria porém eu preciso que apareça o teclado numero do celular exemplo nessa imagem -> http://i.stack.imgur.com/2QTO0.png

Comment: para ativar o teclado numérico, basta colocar o atributo **pattern**: `<input type="text" class="money2" pattern="[0-9]*">`

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou usar:

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" >
```

Comment: Gostaria de mascara, por exemplo quando for digitando ele ir formatando ex: R$ 10.000,63 ou 47,05%